# Best way to transition between two images in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have implemented a pretty simple picture viewer that will allow the user to browse through a collection of images. They are loaded from the Internet, and displayed on the device through a `UIImageView` object. Something like this:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
[img setImage:image];
```

`imageData` is an instance of `NSData` that I use to load the contents of the image from an URL, and `img` is the `UIImageView` instance.

It all works well, but the new image replaces the one being displayed before without any transitions, and I was wondering if there is an easy way to do a good animation transition to improve the user experience.

Any idea how to do this? Code samples would be very appreciated.

Comment: For those of us flipping through it would be great if someone could select an answer. Since this user appears to have left some how...

Answer (score 14):

I was just going through your post and had exactly the same requirement. The problem with all above solutions is, you will have to incorporate the logic of transition into your controller. In the sense the approach is not modular. Instead I wrote this subclass of UIImageView:

**TransitionImageView.h file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface TransitionImageView : UIImageView 
{
    UIImageView *mOriginalImageViewContainerView;
    UIImageView *mIntermediateTransitionView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *originalImageViewContainerView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *intermediateTransitionView;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Animation methods
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)inNewImage withTransitionAnimation:(BOOL)inAnimation;

@end
```

**TransitionImageView.m file:**

```
#import "TransitionImageView.h"

#define TRANSITION_DURATION 1.0

@implementation TransitionImageView
@synthesize intermediateTransitionView = mIntermediateTransitionView;
@synthesize originalImageViewContainerView = mOriginalImageViewContainerView;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [self setOriginalImageViewContainerView:nil];
    [self setIntermediateTransitionView:nil];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Animation methods
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)inNewImage withTransitionAnimation:(BOOL)inAnimation
{
    if (!inAnimation)
    {
        [self setImage:inNewImage];
    }
    else
    {
        // Create a transparent imageView which will display the transition image.
        CGRect rectForNewView = [self frame];
        rectForNewView.origin = CGPointZero;
        UIImageView *intermediateView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectForNewView];
        [intermediateView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [intermediateView setContentMode:[self contentMode]];
        [intermediateView setClipsToBounds:[self clipsToBounds]];
        [intermediateView setImage:inNewImage];

        // Create the image view which will contain original imageView's contents:
        UIImageView *originalView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectForNewView];
        [originalView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [originalView setContentMode:[self contentMode]];
        [originalView setClipsToBounds:[self clipsToBounds]];
        [originalView setImage:[self image]];

        // Remove image from the main imageView and add the originalView as subView to mainView:
        [self setImage:nil];
        [self addSubview:originalView];

        // Add the transparent imageView as subview whose dimensions are same as the view which holds it.
        [self addSubview:intermediateView];

        // Set alpha value to 0 initially:
        [intermediateView setAlpha:0.0];
        [originalView setAlpha:1.0];
        [self setIntermediateTransitionView:intermediateView];
        [self setOriginalImageViewContainerView:originalView];
        [intermediateView release];
        [originalView release];

        // Begin animations:
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"ImageViewTransitions" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:(double)TRANSITION_DURATION];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
        [[self intermediateTransitionView] setAlpha:1.0];
        [[self originalImageViewContainerView] setAlpha:0.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

-(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    // Reset the alpha of the main imageView
    [self setAlpha:1.0];

    // Set the image to the main imageView:
    [self setImage:[[self intermediateTransitionView] image]];

    [[self intermediateTransitionView] removeFromSuperview];
    [self setIntermediateTransitionView:nil];

    [[self originalImageViewContainerView] removeFromSuperview];
    [self setOriginalImageViewContainerView:nil];
}

@end
```

You can even override the `-setImage` method of UIImageView and call my `-setImage:withTransitionAnimation:` method. If it is done like this make sure that you call `[super setImage:]` instead of `[self setImage:]` in the method `-setImage:withTransitionAnimation:` so that it wont end up in infinite recursive call!

-Raj

Answer (score 8):

```
[UIView 
    animateWithDuration:0.2 
    delay:0 
    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
    animations:^{
        self.view0.alpha = 0;
        self.view1.alpha = 1;
    }
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
        view0.hidden = YES;
    }
];
```

Answer (score 4):

The trick is you make two UIImageView instances. You swap them in between calls to UIView +beginAnimations and +commitAnimations.

Answer (score 4):

Please check the answer. I think you are looking for this:

```
imgvw.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your Image name as string"]]];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
[imgvw.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

Comment: This works well, especially with push and transition subtypes.  I think it is the optimal answer in that it does not require creating any fake extra views nor manipulating their geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing different from what's been explained but in code, these are the available transitions:

```
typedef enum {
        UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
        UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
        UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
        UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
        UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
    } UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

**Code** *(Put this in a callback like touchesEnded)*:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];

[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:[self superview] cache:YES];

// -- These don't work on the simulator and the curl up will turn into a fade -- //
//[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:[self superview] cache:YES];
//[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:[self superview] cache:YES];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

// Below assumes you have two subviews that you're trying to transition between
[[self superview] exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it and I agree with Ben View Transitions is a great example. If you are looking for simple full screen transitions I would just consider starting a new utility application and look at toggleView method in the `RootViewController.m`.  Try switching out the `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` and `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight` to `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` and `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown` for a really nice transition effect (this only works on the device).

Answer (score 0):

here is what i have done: a fading.
i put another UIImageView with the same UIImage and dimension called tmp.
i replace the UIImage of the base UIImageView.
Then i put the right image on the base (still covered by tmp).

Next step is 
- to set alpha of tmp to zero, 
- to stretch the base UIImageView to right ratio of the new UIImage based on the height of the base.

Here is the code:

```
    UIImage *img = [params objectAtIndex:0]; // the right image
UIImageView *view = [params objectAtIndex:1]; // the base

UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:view.image]; // the one which will use to fade
tmp.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
[view addSubview:tmp];

view.image = img;
float r = img.size.width / img.size.height;
float h = view.frame.size.height;
float w = h * r;
float x = view.center.x - w/2;
float y = view.frame.origin.y;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

tmp.alpha = 0;
view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);

[UIView commitAnimations];

[tmp performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
[tmp performSelector:@selector(release) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```