# How to animate Layers in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have seen a google application in iPhone.

Application has following facility,

There is a button at bottom right corner, by clicking on that,

entire map folds as if we have folded a page,

I am eager to know how to make this animation.

If you have any idea plz tell me.

Thanks for your help to me.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked here before:

[Best way to transition between two images in a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212689/best-way-to-transition-between-two-images-in-a-uiimageview)

You can read about the curl transition in the [UIView API docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) as well.