# Animate the CHANGE of UIImageView only one image

Tags: iphone, animation, ios4, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView that I would like to change its image with animation. I checked how to animate a UIImageView with an array but I don't wanna use many image.

I just wanna change the current image with a a new one using any kind of animation only once.

Comment: Thanks Control-V. I think that what I wanted actually. I confused animation with transitions. How could i make that an approved answer?

Comment: Yah. I decided to not do any kind of transition. It is too much work for a simple thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can find your answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212689/best-way-to-transition-between-two-images-in-a-uiimageview)

Answer (score 0):

The *animationImages* property works equally well with one image in it, or multiple.

Comment: Sorry Perception. I confused animation with transition. I was looking for transitions in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the below code:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
...
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:"The image name"];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

[imageView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

I think you are searchig for this......