# Image transition example in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, transition

I have an Objective C project that when the user logs in for the first time, there is some processing that needs to happen and it may take about 30 sec.
During this time, I'm showing a progress bar and I also want to show different photos and text (related to each photo) that I fetch for the user from his online profile (using SDWebImage).

**I'm trying to find an example of transition effect between the images**. I'm doing a transition every 1 sec and the problem I'm having is that the images are just appearing (with out any fade in effect or any other effect) and some time the images are not downloaded yet so there is some sort of ugly placeholder.

Any suggestion or example code will be appreciated.

Comment: [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212689/best-way-to-transition-between-two-images-in-a-uiimageview)

Comment: are you trying to only transition between downloaded images? or are you struggling to simply transition between images?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use two CIImages so that you can apply a transition filter (CIFilter) between the two CIImages. This [article](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.310.1.55/1/) has a sample code with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As you’ve figured by experiment, `UIImageView`’s `image` property isn’t animatable.

`CALayer`’s `contents` property, however, is.

If all you want is a simple fade transition, you need not do more than assigning the CGImageRef that underlies your UIImage to the layer’s `contents` and you get a nice fade.

If you need more power, you might want to add a `CATransition`as the animation for the `nil` key of your layer. Now, that will fire the next time you set the contents, unleashing the power of CoreImage filters at low implementation cost.